# Is there an equivalent to 'yield' / 'content_for' in Rhomobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

What I want to do is inject markup into the layout from a template in rhomobile. In rails this is achieved with [yield/content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)

Answer (score 0):

First you should communicate more clearly your intent - Rhodes has it's own terminology and mechanics. In Rhodes, you have 'layouts', 'views', and 'partials', which do not map to Rails equivalents. All content is generally rendered inside a single 'layout' file, which is compiled before the `RhoController` controllers are initialized, so is immutable by the time you have control over dynamic rendering. Standard 'views' are located within directories per `Model`, and are more flexible, as well as `partials`, which are just ERB files prefixex with an underscore.

The rendering capabilities of any ERB file are dictated by the current `Controller`, so for Rhodes layouts, they are rendered before the app launches and you can't dynamically change the content. With ERB files elsewhere it is more flexible. Read more here: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/ui